# Spark select query fails on a large dataset in hive table

Tags: apache, scala, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

My below code is reading data from a hive table using spark.
The table has 100 million records in it. When I select this many records in my Rdd and try to do a result.show() it gives serious problem exception.

I basically want to insert records in other table by selecting just a few columns from this table for 100 million record set.

Here is my code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)

val result=sqlContext.sql("Select * from ******reception.recp_customer")

result: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [data_source_id: smallint, customer_bkey: string ... 129 more fields]

result.show()

java.lang.RuntimeException: serious problem
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.generateSplitsInfo(OrcInputFormat.java:1064)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.getSplits(OrcInputFormat.java:1091)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:202)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:311)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2371)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2773)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1(Dataset.scala:2370)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect(Dataset.scala:2377)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2113)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2112)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withTypedCallback(Dataset.scala:2803)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2112)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2327)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:248)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:636)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:595)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:604)
  ... 52 elided
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0000312_0000"
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.generateSplitsInfo(OrcInputFormat.java:1041)
  ... 94 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0000312_0000"
  at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
  at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:441)
  at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:483)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.AcidUtils.parseDelta(AcidUtils.java:323)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.AcidUtils.getAcidState(AcidUtils.java:394)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$FileGenerator.callInternal(OrcInputFormat.java:658)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$FileGenerator$1.run(OrcInputFormat.java:648)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$FileGenerator$1.run(OrcInputFormat.java:645)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:421)
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1595)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$FileGenerator.call(OrcInputFormat.java:645)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$FileGenerator.call(OrcInputFormat.java:626)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Clueless about what is causing this.I understand data set is huge how to process it.

Comment: It clearly states `NumberFormatException`

Comment: Hi,If I fire the same query in hive shell it works fine.So, I have also fired insert query on some other tables using records from this table using hive although I had to set few parameters for skewed data.In spark when I try then it is giving the error.Assuming it to be issue with 100 million dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your `hive` table is an `ACID` table. For `acid` tables you can use only `hive` to query, you cannot use `spark` to query them as this feature is not yet supported in spark.

You can follow the below `JIRA` ticket for reference
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15348

Answer (score 0):

Run major compaction on your hive table and then try to read your table from spark shell or from your code it must work.

run after connecting hive

> ALTER TABLE .recp_customer COMPACT 'major';

Answer (score -1):

The line:
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0000312_0000"
shows that you are trying to use a String value as it is numeric. Check it out.

Comment: Hi,If I fire the same query in hive shell it works fine.So, I have also fired insert query on some other tables using records from this table using hive although I had to set few parameters for skewed data.In spark when I try then it is giving the error.Assuming it to be issue with 100 million dataset.